# How to hide my JWT token On Javascript Ajax API Call from Frontend?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, api, jwt

My Question is that I was Implemented JWT Token When User is logged In. Also Done some test Through POSTMAN. Getting token when User is validating with username and password. Now My API is completed and whenever Front-end Guy needs API Calls, He have to pass JWT token. Now This token is visible on AJAX API call. Is there any way that I can Hide all token so that Attacker won't get this token?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Although the question is not suited for Stackoverflow, short answer: yes tokens are visible in Ajax calls. That's totally normal. You cannot hide them.

Answer (score 0):

jwt is not secured by default.

first if you want to work with jwt in your website,it must work on https.

second if you store it on a cookie use the cookie http only option to prevent javascript cookie hijack

also you can use jwt in OAuth for more features